# Titanium SDK 3.1.1 issues

Tags: ios, sdk, titanium

When the app was upgraded from 2.1.4 to 3.1.0, the targets were updated successfully as shown in TiApp.xml

[image: When the app was upgraded from 2.1.4 to 3.1.0, the targets were updated successfully as shown]

But when upgraded from 3.1.0 to 3.1.1 it became this -

[image: But when upgraded from 3.1.0 to 3.1.1 it became this]

Please let me know what I missed to make these deployment targets active.
Thanks in Advance.

EDIT :
No error messages - i'm not able to build my application. I have -
Xcode - V4.6 and
Node.js - V0.8.22

Comment: Please show your Error message!
and may be update you xCode with updated version...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that the SDK's download was interrupted multiple times and even though there was a folder named 3.1.1GA, it hardly had about 30 MB of files.

For others facing the same issue,
At the path `/Users/Admin/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/3.1.1.GA`
please check whether all the files are present (roughly about 500MB). If not, delete the folder,restart Titanium Studio and start the download again.

Answer (score 0):

click on ?. It shows the message. In that way you can get idea of what should be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

1. Check your Titanium dashboard and check under the heading 'Get started' if your Native SDK's are correctly configured.
2. Check your Titanium settings (preferences -> Studio -> Platforms) if all settings are correct.
3. Toggle to XML view (bottom Overview | tiapp.xml) in tiapp.xml and manually change the deployment targets

   ```
   <deployment-targets>
       <target device="tizen">false</target>
       <target device="mobileweb">false</target>
       <target device="iphone">true</target>
       <target device="ipad">false</target>
       <target device="android">true</target>
       <target device="blackberry">false</target>
   </deployment-targets>
   ```